# Papaja abstract indentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, papaja

in a papaja-generated document, why is the first paragraph of the abstract not properly indented - see the offset between "Intro." and "Conclusion.", while both should be equally indented if I read the YAML correctly.

```
---
title             : "My title"
shorttitle        : "My shorttitle"

author: 
  - name          : "John Doe"
    affiliation   : "1"
    corresponding : yes    # Define only one corresponding author
    address       : "Postal address"
    email         : "my@email.com"

affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : "University of Annoying Typesetting"

abstract: |

  Intro. This is my introduction
  
  Conclusion. This is my conclusion
  
  
keywords          : "keywords"
wordcount         : "X"

floatsintext      : no
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : no
mask              : no
draft             : no
figsintext        : yes
header-includes:
documentclass     : "apa7"
classoption       : "man"
output:
  papaja::apa6_pdf:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen when an author note is included on the first page. Until this is fixed in the package, you can do the following:

```yaml
abstract: |
  \raggedright
  Intro. This is my introduction
  
  Conclusion. This is my conclusion
```